# How do I display postgresql database table data on a web browser using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new in python and sqlalchemy and need help here. i'm trying to display the data stored in the postgresql database table to the browser. I got no error message but the table on the browser seems not to be fetching the data from the table. i get no data displayed on the browser but i have data stored in the postgresql database.

I'm using sqlalchemy and i've created a data class and rendered a table in the html view which is supposed to display the table rows from the postgresql database.

Heres my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import jinja2

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ='postgresql://postgres:paswword@localhost/TendersQuotes'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
#app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres123@localhost/TendersQuotes'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Tenderslist"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    t_company=db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    t_title=db.Column(db.String(180), nullable=False)
    t_number=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    t_type=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    t_status=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    t_duedate=db.Column(db.DateTime(),nullable=False)
    t_cperson=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    t_cperson_email=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    t_cperson_no=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    t_comments=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, t_company, t_title, t_number, t_type, t_status, t_duedate, t_cperson, t_cperson_email, t_cperson_no, t_comments):
        self.t_company= t_company
        self.t_title=t_title
        self.t_number=t_number
        self.t_type=t_type
        self.t_status=t_status
        self.t_duedate=t_duedate
        self.t_cperson=t_cperson
        self.t_cperson_email=t_cperson_email
        self.t_cperson_no=t_cperson_no
        self.t_comments=t_comments

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/tenders")
def tenders():
    tenders = Data.query.all()
    return render_template('tenders.html', tenders=tenders)
```

then on the view page, i have the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>....</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


<h2>List of Tenders</h2>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>S/No.</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Tender Title</th>
        <th>Tender No.</th>
        <th>Tender Type</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>Contact Person</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {% for item in tenders %}
           <tr>
             <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[4]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[5]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[6]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[7]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[8]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[9]}}</td>
             <td>{{item[10]}}</td>

           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
   </tbody>

  </table>

</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something I'm missing here? coz i I only get an out put of the table head and not the table data, which is supposed to be fetched from the database.

I need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only code that I see that looks incorrect would be in your view the `item` variable is going to be an instance of `Data` so you should not access it like a dictionary.

```html
{% for item in tenders %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.t_company }}</td>

        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Otherwise, you need to check your database. With SQLAlchemy, you're initializing the database properly via the `SQLAlchemy` class, but you also need to make sure to actually create the database via the `create_all` method.

```sh
$ python

>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

You can see that in the [flask-sqlalchemy quickstart guide](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/).

Once you run that, you should confirm the structure in Postgres. Log in to the database via `psql` and check that the tables and columns exist.

Then you need to confirm that you actually have data in the database. Run a `SELECT` on the table with `psql` and see if any data exists. If it doesn't, seed the database either via your `Data` object and python or by running `CREATE` queries directly against the database.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The only thing i needed was actually the correction you made here ```{% for item in tenders %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.t_company }}</td>

        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}``` everything other thing was alright. I applied the change and it worked fine. thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that helped you out.